# SQL After trigger update value that triggers update

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have 2 tables, shipment and invoice. I have an after trigger that updates the shipment table with the invoice number from the invoice table.The invoice table has their related shipment numbers, can be more than one for each invoice.

```
Create Trigger ShipmentInvoice
on Therefore.dbo.Invoice
For Insert
AS
Update cat set
  invoice = Fac.invoice
FROM therefore.dbo.thecat10 cat
INNER JOIN therefore.dbo.vFacturaAlbaran alb
  on alb.shipment COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS = alb.shipment
```

This Works but it updates the whole table every time. I need a way to update the shipment table only with the values that were recently added in the invoice table when the trigger is activated.

## Edit

The trigger is over the invoice table. I am updating the shipment table with the invoice numbers from the invoice table.

Comment: There is a `INSERTED` table you need to use it there if you are looking for just the inserted rows

Comment: We don't see that the trigger on the `invoice ` table, it's on `Therefore.dbo.TheCat10` table

Comment: @Sami looks like the OP has udpated their SQL finally. :)

Answer (score 0):

> This Works but it updates the whole table every time. I need a way to update the shipment table only with the values that were recently added in the invoice table when the trigger is activated.

That because you are joining both tables, you need to use `INSERTED` table to get only the inserted rows as :

```
Create Trigger ShipmentInvoice
on Therefore.dbo.Invoice
For Insert
AS
Update cat set
  invoice = I.invoice
FROM therefore.dbo.thecat10 cat
INNER JOIN INSERTED I alb ON Cat.ID = I.ID
...
```

Comment: This seems wrong. `alb` in the OP's query is `therefore.dbo.vFacturaAlbaran`, however, `inserted`, in yours references (inserted) rows from `Therefore.dbo.TheCat10`. These aren't the same.

Comment: @Larnu It seems like he has a lot of wrong thing there not just this

Comment: Yeah, their comment on my answer makes no sense based on the information we have.

Answer (score 0):

it seems odd that you are updating the table to you are already inserting into; why are you not resolving the correct value before hand? This is pseudo-sql, but will get you on the right path

```
CREATE TRIGGER ShipmentInvoice
ON Therefore.dbo.Invoice
FOR INSERT
AS
    UPDATE cat
    SET invoice = Fac.invoice --There is no table/alias Fac, where is this coming from? inserted?
    FROM therefore.dbo.thecat10 cat
         JOIN inserted i ON cat.{Primary/Foreign ID COLUMN} = i.{Primary/Foreign ID COLUMN}
         INNER JOIN therefore.dbo.vFacturaAlbaran alb ON alb.shipment COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS = alb.shipment;
```

Note the items in the braces (`{}`) and also my comment about your object `Fac`.

Comment: The invoice comes last, so i update the shipment with the invoice number from the invoice table. The trigger is actually on the invoice table.

Comment: @AlexE. The trigger, according to your SQL, is on the table `Therefore.dbo.TheCat10`. There is no "invoice table"; unless `TheCat10` is your invoice table?

Comment: @AlexE. updated based on your latest SQl. It helps, however, if you provide the correct SQL the first time. Please try to be vigliant when supplying sample code and make sure it reflects your actual SQL. :)